# Is there a way to save the value of a constantly changing Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I'm working with a large pandas DataFrame that my script constantly updates, my problem is that I'm trying to calculate the difference between the length of the latests version of my Df and the length of the previous one.

The df is assigned to a variable, so how can I access the previous value of my variable so I can calculate the difference with its current value?

Comment: assign the dfs to different variables

Comment: You can append all values in a `list` or use a dictionary where `key` will be iteration and `value` will be the corresponding value of dynamic variable

Comment: Karl would not that be just two different names referring to the same value? So, as soon as the df updates both variable would update and their difference would be 0. I'd appreciate if you could correct me if Im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help :)

```
# The dataframe you have
df = pandas.DataFrame(previous)

# The updated dataframe
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(latest)

# Compare them in the way you want
compare(df, new_df)

# Store the latest dataframe and "drop" the old one if you don't need it anymore
df = new_df
```

Comment: Thanks Vivian, but I don't think this works in my case as I create my df from a data set from a website through a GET request so, df = pandas.DataFrame(previous) and new_df = pandas.DataFrame(latest) would result in the same df as they both use the same data.

Comment: I assumed that the first command is executed some seconds / minutes / hours before :)